# Blacklist domains?

Tags: feature-request, spam

Any way that we can add domains to a blacklist? I'm thinking a list of known spam related links that will require a 2000+ or 3000+ rep to link to in a post. If this already exists, there are a few password reset related domains that should be blacklisted. They're recurring problems. I'd post them here, but don't want to give them publicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this already exists.  Domains are only added when people spam them with manual moderator action.  If you have particular recommendations, you can ask a moderator or e-Mail the team.  If they're a recurring problem, you should post them here.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure blacklisting the domains is the way to go.  Since most of them are tied to a few questions about password recovery it may be easier to flag the questions and request that our moderators set those questions to [protected](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/new-protected-question-status/).  I suspect even the small rep requirement will prevent most of the drive-by posts about various password recovery tools that seem to be accumulating on a few questions.

- [How to reset Windows XP password on Dell server with RAID?](https://serverfault.com/questions/160475/how-to-reset-windows-xp-password-on-dell-server-with-raid)
- [Obtaining administrator access to Windows XP (lost password)](https://serverfault.com/questions/154006/obtaining-administrator-access-to-windows-xp-lost-password)
- [Administrator password reset in Windows Server 2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/115028/administrator-password-reset-in-windows-server-2008)
- [incorrect password when computer is locked](https://serverfault.com/questions/49179/incorrect-password-when-computer-is-locked)
- [How do I keep the local admin password consistent across an OU?](https://serverfault.com/questions/32193/how-do-i-keep-the-local-admin-password-consistent-across-an-ou)

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice, wouldn't it? Such a system would require maintenance. Keep flagging 'em! I'll make a note to keep track of the password tag m'self. I flagged many of those a week or so ago, didn't know they were back.